# Does $a+b$ divide $2ab$ if $a$ is not equal to $b$ and both numbers are natural (0 is not considered)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I tried plugging in numbers and I couldn't find a case where they were divisible. So I started thinking of a proof that they are never divisible, but I couldn't come up with anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$2ab=2a(a+b)-2a^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Write $a=dx$ and $b=dy$ where $d=\gcd(a,b)$ then $x,y$ are relatively prime and we have $$x+y\mid 2dxy $$

Since $\gcd(x+y,x)=\gcd(x+y,y)=1$ we have further $x+y\mid 2d$ and that is all we can conclude.

---

*Proof that $\gcd(x+y,y)=1$:*

Let $p\mid x+y$ and $p\mid y$ then $p\mid (x+y)-y=p$. So $p\mid \gcd(x,y) =1$ and thus $p=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $a=2$, $b=6$. Then $2ab=24$ and $a+b=8$. In that case $a+b$ divides $2ab$.